# What is the difference between + and ++ when concatenating nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, nvarchar

I just saw sql code which concats 2 strings with '++'. I always use single plus like '+'

what is the point of using '++'

```
 PRINT 'TEST ' ++ 'TEST'
```

Comment: Probably just a typo. t_sql will ignore repeated plus signs. PRINT 'TEST ' ++++++++++++ 'TEST'

Comment: Interesting . . . I don't have SQL Server on hand at this instant, but it is possible that it would parse as` 'TEST' + (+ 'TEST')` and return an error because the unary positive operator is expecting a numeric.  On the other hand, unary `+` does nothing to a number, so perhaps it has the same behavior on a string.

Comment: @SeanLange, serving up alley-oops to answers since 2014

Comment: lol @scsimon I didn't bother to look up the documentation to provide an actual answer. But I throw up a lot of meatballs for others to hit over the fence into an answer. I don't really care about points so it doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PRINT 'TEST ' ++++++++++++ 'TEST'
```

or

```
PRINT 5+++++++++++++++++++++2
```

Still works because, 
"Although a unary plus can appear before any numeric expression, it performs no operation on the value returned from the expression. "

Look into below documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174362.aspx